# Can't get passed Google Drive "Choose Account" screen in Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to incorporate the Google Drive API within my android application.

I have added google play services to my `build.gradle` along with getting the Android API key. My issue is within the `OnResume()` where the user picks the account.

It just keeps reprompting the user to choose account and does not proceed.

May anyone help me ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    private static final String TAG = "Google Drive Activity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
    private static final  int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 2;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean fileOperation = false;
    private DriveId mFileId;
    public DriveFile file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

            // disconnect Google API client connection
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }


        try {   
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    public void onClickCreateFile(View view){
        fileOperation = true;
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }

    public void onClickOpenFile(View view){
        fileOperation = false;
        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }

    public void OpenFileFromGoogleDrive(){
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain", "text/html" })
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
        }
    }


    final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        if (fileOperation == true) {
                            CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(result);
                        } else {
                            OpenFileFromGoogleDrive();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


    public void CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result){
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello abhay!");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("abhaytest2")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file created: "+""+
                                result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                    final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    mFileId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                            OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                    Log.e("file id", mFileId.getResourceId() + "");
                    String url = "https://drive.google.com/open?id="+ mFileId.getResourceId();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my manifest. Blocking the API Key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.moli9479csumb.version1googledrive">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyD_2eJ5pPdRMysVwxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Asking a silly question here, but did you enable the Drive API in your Google developer console?

Comment: @Rajeev ha yes I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite "Choose an account" loop when using Google Drive API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503195/infinite-choose-an-account-loop-when-using-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 0):

You get the AccountSelector when the GoogleApiClient is not able to connect and has a resolution which requires the user to authorize the App for the API. This happens when you call "result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);" from the onConnectionFailed method.

Once the user selects the account your activity gets a callback with the code REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION. This code must be handled and you should call apiClient.connect() to connect again when this code is received in onActivityResult method.

See [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api) for more details. I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily force to prompt the user to choose account by using [`Account Picker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account, java.util.ArrayList, java.lang.String[], boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], android.os.Bundle)), common account picker is similar to the standard framework account picker introduced in `newChooseAccountIntent`. Returns an intent to an Activity that prompts the user to choose from a list of accounts. The caller will then typically start the activity by calling `startActivityForResult(intent, ...)`;.

On success the activity returns a Bundle with the account name and type specified using keys [KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME) and [KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE).

The most common case is to call this with one account type, e.g.:

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"},
false, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The account picker activity will return when the user has selected and/or created an account, and the resulting account name can be retrieved as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode,
final Intent data) {
if (requestCode == SOME_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
}
}
```

Here's the Official Google Sample code which uses the above code with concrete explanation how to use API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android#step_5_setup_the_sample

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your onResume() and onConnectionFailded() methods.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }


    try {   
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}
```

What happens?

In onResume() you create GoogleApiClient and call connect(). Connection fails because you are not authorized with an account. Method onConnectionFailed() is executed which opens a resolution which is actually another activity called for result. You choose an acount but I guess authorization fails or is cancelled.
You return to your original activity and onResume() is executed. And you go a full circle again.
Why does your authorization fail? I guess because there is something wrong with your credentials. Go to Developer console and create O Auth credentials for your package and your key signature.