# Google Drive API oauth 2 error

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I managed to get the code runing to a point where i can upload and download files in my android app from google drive using the api. However i uploaded my app to Google Play and when a user installs it the first time the oauth 2 screen pops up and requires to select account(which is great) but when the user selects Google account the oauth screen just keep appearing and looping.
Did anyone encounter this before?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503195/infinite-choose-an-account-loop-when-using-google-drive-api), maybe you did not create credentials for your app. As described in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started), you must retrieve your SHA-1 keys for both the debug and production environments and add them in your credentials in the Google Developers Console.

Comment: i did create Oauth client for debug and release using sha-1 fingerprint of debug and release. still no luck.