# Choose Account Screen for Google Drive API keeps repeating. Tried every other solution on here

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I keep getting the choose account screen repeating itself even after selecting an account to use.  This is for google drive on an android app.  I have checked that the SHA-1 key was installed on the google api register, I've done everything by the book but still getting this annoying thing.  Below is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.components.integrategoogle">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCOO-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Below is the java source:

```
package com.example.android.components.integrategoogle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "Google Drive Activity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;
    private static final  int REQUEST_CODE_OPENER = 2;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean fileOperation = false;
   // private DriveId mFileId;
   // public DriveFile file;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity will start interacting with the user.
     * At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack,
     * with user input going to it.
     */

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
            // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
            // failures.
            // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

            // disconnect Google API client connection
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {


        // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());

        if (!result.hasResolution()) {

            // show the localized error dialog.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
            return;
        }

        /**
         *  The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
         *  Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an  authorization
         *  dialog is displayed to the user.
         */

        try {

            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * It invoked when Google API client connected
     * @param connectionHint
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * It invoked when connection suspend
     * @param cause
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    public void onClickCreateFile(View view) {
        fileOperation = true;
        // Create new contents resource

        Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
    }

    final ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback =
            new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Made it to before successful connection");
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        if (fileOperation == true) {
                            CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

    public void CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents
                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                try {
                    writer.write("Hello abhay!");
                    writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("abhaytest2")
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setStarred(true).build();

                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents)
                        .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    /**
     * Handle result of Created file
     */
    final private ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
            ResultCallback<DriveFolder.DriveFileResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveFolder.DriveFileResult result) {
                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file created: " + "" + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            };

}
```

Below is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.components.integrategoogle.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/create_a_file_on_google_drive"
        android:onClick="onClickCreateFile"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/openfile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/createfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open_file_from_google_drive"
        android:onClick="onClickOpenFileMethod"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503195/infinite-choose-an-account-loop-when-using-google-drive-api

Comment: Hi Brett. What *other solutions* have you tried exactly? It'll be better if you point them out in order to avoid duplicate efforts from the community.

Comment: ok I'll give yours a go altu.  Hopefully it works with oauth because I haven't tried with oauth yet - only with using the appid.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I hadn't created a new OAuth Client ID.  Without it, the client cannot be authorized against the SHA-1 code and packagename.